# Rspec: Custom failure message for raise_error test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, error-handling

I'd like to use [customised failure messages](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/customized-message) when [testing if an error was raised or not](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/expect-error) while visiting a page with capybara.

My code:

```
expect(visit '/page/path').to_not raise_error(ActionView::Template::Error), "my custom error message"
```

I have also tried to use the lambda syntax (`lambda { "my custom error message" }`) with no success.

The problem seems to be that the error itself gets precedence for display over my custom error message. I have no interest in the error message - if one is raised, I know what the problem is, and the custom error message gives the solution (it's a long story involving VCR).

Right now I have a sketchy `begin/rescue` that looks like this:

```
begin
  expect(visit '/page/path').to_not raise_error(ActionView::Template::Error)
rescue ActionView::Template::Error => error
  expect(1).to eq(0), "my custom error message"
end
```

But, as you can see, I have to write a fake, always failing test, `expect(1).to eq(0)` which seems silly.

Is there any way to force my message to be displayed from the inline custom error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the following working locally:

```
expect { visit '/page/path' }.to_not raise_error, "Nope"
```

Specifying the class of exception you expect *to_not* have raised is apparently deprecated, according to RSpec's yelling at the top of the test results:

```
DEPRECATION: `expect { }.not_to raise_error(SpecificErrorClass)` is
deprecated. Use `expect { }.not_to raise_error` (with no args) instead.
```

Comment: Thanks! It turns out I needed to use the `{}` (not `()`) for the expect. Once I made that change I got the error message you talked about. And after that was fixed, the message came through as expected.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you'll need to pass the block you want to execute to the expect method in order for the `raise_error` matcher to catch the errors raised in the block. Perhaps surprisingly the following fails for this reason:

```
describe 'Foo' do
  it 'raises an error' do
    expect(fail "wat").to raise_error(RuntimeError)
  end
end
```

But if we re-write that expectation as follows it passes:

```
expect{fail "wat"}.to raise_error(RuntimeError)
```

As Rob mentioned though if you want to specify that an error is not raised you'll need to write your expectation as follows:

```
expect{fail "wat"}.to_not raise_error
```

and using that format you can specify a custom error message:

```
expect{fail "wat"}.to_not raise_error, "custom error message"
```

The reason why your second block of code seems to work is your `visit '/page/path'` raises an exception, then your exception handler catches it. It would be equivalent to the following:

```
begin
  visit '/page/path'
rescue ActionView::Template::Error => error
  expect(1).to eq(0), "my custom error message"
end
```